# How to get a list of week number with year(202114 in this format) using python or pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

How to get a list of week number with year(202114 in this format) using python or pyspark.
considering todays date (202114) the output should be {202113,202112,202111,202110,202109,202108}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use datetime's function isocalendar to get the current week number:

```
from datetime import date
year, week_num, day_num = date.today().isocalendar()
```

After that, you could use a simple for loop to iterate over the last 6 weeks:

```
weeks = []
for i in range(1, 7):
    weeks.append(str(year) + str(week_num - i))
```

This should leave you a list that looks like this:
['202113', '202112'..., '20219', '20218']

if that's a problem and you need '20218' to be '202108', use this:

```
weeks = []
for i in range(1, 7):
    curr_week = week_num - i
    str_week = str(curr_week) if len(str(curr_week)) == 2 else f'0{curr_week}'
    weeks.append(str(year) + str_week)
```

You could probably write this in a much cleaner way but I hope this helped.

Comment: if i use range(1,16) it gives 202100 as output which is wrong because week number starts from 1 right?